# pug вложенный миксин

Tags: pug, mixins

Всем привет, помогите разобраться с миксинами в pug. Мне нужно, чтобы один миксин входил во вложенность другого

```html
mixin cards(header, image)
  ._cards-list--el
    ._cards-list--el-header= header
    img(src=image)._cards-list--el-image
mixin content(image, title)
  ._cards-list--el-content
    img(src=image)._cards-list--el-content--image
    ._cards-list--el-content--title= title
    
._cards
  ._cards-list
    +cards('header', 'image')
    +content('image', 'title')
```

Как сделать так, чтобы второй миксин входил внутри первого, чтобы получалось следующее:

```html
<div class="_cards">
  <div class="_cards-list">
    <div class="_cards-list--el">
      <div class="_cards-list--el-header">header</div>
      <img class="_cards-list--el-image" src="image"/>
      <div class="_cards-list--el-content">
        <img class="_cards-list--el-content--image" src="image"/>
        <div class="_cards-list--el-content--title">title</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Полагаю, [тут](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html) Вы найдете нужную информацию.

Comment: Там идет речь просто о миксинах, нет ни слова, как вложить результат одного миксина в другой. Это было бы здорово

Comment: А [здесь](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html) все прочитали?

Comment: Там вроде бы про вложенные шаблоны, а мне нужно формировать тело карточки из одного миксина и контентные строки из другого, которые входят в контейнер из первого миксина

Answer (score 1):

В хвосте родительского миксина добавляем block и второй миксин сделаем вложенным в родительский

```
mixin cards(header, image)
  ._cards-list--el
    ._cards-list--el-header= header
    img(src=image)._cards-list--el-image
    block

mixin content(image, title)
  ._cards-list--el-content
    img(src=image)._cards-list--el-content--image
    ._cards-list--el-content--title= title
._cards
  ._cards-list
    +cards('header', 'image')
      +content('image', 'title')
```

Получил разметку:

```
<div class="_cards">
  <div class="_cards-list">
    <div class="_cards-list--el">
      <div class="_cards-list--el-header">header</div>
      <img class="_cards-list--el-image" src="image">
      <div class="_cards-list--el-content">
        <img class="_cards-list--el-content--image" src="image">
        <div class="_cards-list--el-content--title">title</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```